# Closed invariant set $X$ with $\omega(x)=\alpha(x)=X$ for all $x\in X$ must be compact

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is an exercise from the book "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra" of Hirsch and Smale, page  242:

Let $X$ be an closed invariant set for a $C^1$ dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\phi_t(x)$ is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\in X$. Suppose that $\alpha(x) = \omega(x)=X$ for all $x\in X$. Prove that $X$ is compact.

Here, $\omega(x)$ denotes the $\omega$-limit set of the unique solution $\phi(t;0,x)=\phi_t(x)$ and $\alpha(x)$ the $\alpha$-limit set.

Could someone give me some hints on how to solve this problem?